# How to I create an Outlook 2010 search folder to show all sent messages?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

In the case of Outlook 2010 talking to Exchange, the "Sent Items" folder is an actual folder in that if you move a message out of that folder, it disappears from "Sent Items".  In contrast the Lotus Notes behavior is that "Sent" is a logical view (like an Outlook Search Folder) so when you "move" items elsewhere they still show up in Sent, but really the one in Sent is a pointer to the one in the folder where you moved it.  So in Notes the Sent folder is a listing of ALL sent emails (assuming the messages hasn't been deleted obviously), regardless of if the message has been moved.

How do I achieve the same effect in Outlook 2010 with Search Folders?  I've tried this

[image]

and the result is not only do I *not* see some emails sent by me, but also I see emails that were originally sent by me AND the replies to those emails.  I suspect that since the reply has a 'from me' in there (since I originally sent it), that it includes that email in the view.

I've also tried

[image]

with the same result.

Comment: Are you entering the email address or picking it from the list the exchange server provides?

Comment: @RSMoser - I retried what I did in the first screenshot and it's working, so I must have somehow screwed it up the first time.  I'm going to modify my question to just ask how to do this.  If you want to take that first screenshot and post it as the answer I'd be happy to accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this but used the template "Mail from specific people" and it seems to achieve the result you were looking for. I too started out looking at a custom search folder but the template seems to implement the correct logic.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and put my own name there (selected from the address book) and got like 1% of the results I'd expect.  Any thoughts on what I could have done wrong?